# How does one differentiate a "fly by" from a "fly over" waypoint?

Tags: instrument-procedures, waypoint

I am referring more to Terminal Area Procedures (SID, STAR, Approach), rather than en route waypoints, airways etc. How do I know if such a waypoint is a "fly over" or not?

Especially for some RNAV procedures, where the turn to join the final approach course can be 90 degrees. I have already read the "[Fly over or fly by question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/57392/62)" but I did not find a reply to the above, although the example quoted and shown in that question was a very good example of what I am asking.

Comment: Are you asking what the chart symbols are? [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11681/62) might also be relevant.

Comment: Are you referring to the waypoints as depicted on the FMC legs page? . . . or chart symbology? Remember FMC legs and vertical profile must be checked against the published procedure before shooting an approach.

Comment: I am referring to both actually, but specifically referring to SID, STAR and Approaches (both Instrument and RNAV) Does the FMC show the difference? And are they shown differently on the ND?

Answer (score 8):

A flyover waypoint will have a circle drawn around it on a chart, whereas a fly-by waypoint will not. (Easy to remember: the circle looks like the **O** in **O**ver)

> The symbols for a fly-by and a flyover waypoint in aeronatutial maps and charts can be differenciated by the circle surrouning flyover waypoints.

[image]

https://skybrary.aero/articles/waypoint